# How can I add a SPACE halfway through a string value?

Tags: c#, string, .net-micro-framework

I'm trying to create a STRING in JSON format. However, one of the fields (from my editing/removing ALL spaces) now leaves a line like `"START":"13/08/1410:30:00"`. However, I want to add a space between the date and time? I have tried using the ToCharArray() method to split the string, but I am at a loss as to how to add a space between the DATE and TIME part of the string?

For Example, i am trying to get: `"START":"13/08/14 10:30:00"` but instead am getting

```
"START":"13/08/1410:30:00"
```

Please note. The length of the string before the space requirement will always be 17 characters long. I am using VS 2010 for NETMF (Fez Panda II)

Comment: I have attempted (although not with the string builder part) the gen. idea behind @No1_Melman 's approach (where, while generating the string (lots of editing/removing lots of spaces/adding to JSON format/reading data from serialport/etc) but it seems to 'skip' this. - No error in debugger, it just refuses to print this JSON now!

Comment: But that could've been a hardware issue tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the split position is always 17, then simply:

```
string t = s.Substring(0, 17) + " " + s.Substring(17);
```

Comment: I can see how this would work. Could I ask if you could suggest how to cope if the value DID change (p.s. sorry for the follow up Q)?

Comment: @terrible That depends on what the rules are for the new pattern. A regex would be the first thought for a general-purpose pattern match/replace tool

Comment: You can use `string.Insert` which is probably the most rarely used string method on the planet. It is so rarely used that Marc Gravell doesn't know it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you will have to sort the numbers out, but thats the general idea.

```
String.Format("{0} {1}", dateString.Substring(0, 17), dateString.Substring(17, dateString.Length - 17);
```

Or you can use the `StringBuilder` class:

```
var finalString = new StringBuilder();
for (var i = 0; i < dateString.Length; i++){
    if (i == 17)
        finalString.Add(" ");
    else
        finalString.Add(dateString.ToCharArray()[i]);
}
return finalString.ToString();
```

Comment: That erases the `1` from `10:30`

Comment: Edited it, I did do it off the top of my head. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the date time format always the same you can use [`string.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
var output = @"""START"":""13/08/1410:30:00""".Insert(17, " ");
```

Comment: very cute; I fixed up the string literal, but: very nice approach

Comment: if you have an `@` then you don't need to double up the quotes surely?

Comment: @No1_Melman yes, you still need to double them; with a verbatim string literal, `"` => `""` is the **only** escape needed; it replaces `"` => `\"` and a wide range of other slash-escapes

Comment: The bad news is: I don't think NETMF *has* a `string.Insert` method ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee436418.aspx)) - but still a great answer, for non-NETMF readers

Answer (score -1):

Strings in .Net are immutable: you can never change them. However, you can easily create a new string.

```
var date_time = dateString + " " + timeString;
```